# How to share log in sessions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, session, cookies

I have been reading about sessions all day, I am hoping someone can clearly explain how I can share a session between app.example.io and example.io

*A subdomain is technically a completely different domain, it's not just the browser, so you have to use a Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header and pass the passport credentials*

Is the above true, should I stop worrying about configuring my session or cookie like below and focus on passing credentials from one domain to the other?

```
// I have been trying to configure the domain property to no avail
app.use(cookieSession({ 
    key: 'example.sid',
    secret: 'something',
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        domain: '.example.io',
        maxAge: 1000
    }
}));
```

I have tried configuring my session for over 24 hours, I am convinced I need to pass credentials over, so if that is true my question is how do I pass over credentials that have been authenticated by passport.js?

My node.js server is all using one express app, the subdomains come from the npm subdomain module which proxies requests to `subdomain/app`. Therefore the subdomain and domain technically do share the same session in the server setup?

All in all I am confused and would be relieved if someone can clear the air for me.

Comment: Setting the domain for the session cookie this way should be enough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178104/node-js-passport-session-cookie-domain

Comment: I am not sure why it's not working, what I do notice is the name of the particular cookie that is created for the login session is named `connect.sid` and I see on app.example.io there is a `connect.sid` for example.io and a separate one for app.example.io

Comment: Is it possible inside my app the sessions are being created individually. The goal is to obviously have a  user login to one side and be logged into both.

Comment: I think the mongoStore is a key component in sharing the session, I would use redisStore but is it that important? Does that mean one session is created for the multiple domains? Does each domain connect to the redis dataStore opposed to the default one perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some intense research, I have my head wrapped around this for the most part.

I noticed google analytics cookie works for all my sub-domains because the domain on the cookie when looking at it in the console has only a period `.example.io` while looking at the cookies my express app was creating looked like `app.example.io` & `example.io`. So obviously I needed the cookie domain to look like `.example.io` for both domains.

The session code that I found works best for this is below.

```
app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore(), 
  key: 'example.sid', 
  secret: 'keyboard cat', 
  cookie:{ domain: '.example.io' }
}));
```

I hardly tried using the `key` so by setting a key it looks like that helped, also IDK if the store does anything, but on my live server I installed redis and included it in my project, not sure if that made a difference.

Also notice the domain set in the cookie has the `.example.io`. This WORKED, I am relieved, I will keep testing to make sure I am not fooled.

Hope this helps someone!